# Rails NoMethodError 'each' when trying to destroy record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nomethoderror

I have a rails application with some tables (Answer, Question, Project) Answer is linked to Question via a foreign key, my destroy method in my QUESTION controller is defined like so:

```
def destroy
        @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
        @pregunta.destroy
        flash[:danger] = "Se ha borrado la pregunta"
        redirect_to questions_path
    end
```

My ANSWER model has the following constraints:

```
belongs_to :question, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :answers_projects, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :projects, through: :answers_projects, :dependent => :destroy
```

but when I'm trying to call my destroy method like so (In my view):

```
<% @preguntas.each do |pregunta| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= pregunta.question %></td>
      <td><%= pregunta.get_process_name %></td>
      <td><%= pregunta.input %></td>
      <td><%= pregunta.count_op %></td>
      <td><%= pregunta.area %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', question_path(pregunta), class: "btn btn-xs btn-info" %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_question_path(pregunta) , class: "btn btn-xs btn-warning"%></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'DELETE',question_path(pregunta),method: :delete, data: {confirm: '¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar la pregunta? Esta acción no se puede deshacer'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger"%></td>
```

I can destroy the record in my development environment, but in my deployment environment I get an error with the following in my Heroku Logs:

```
AnswersProject Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "answers_projects".* FROM "answers_projects" WHERE "answers_projects"."answer_id" = $1  [["answer_id", 95]]
2018-02-02T23:14:19.329550+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a]    (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
2018-02-02T23:14:19.337619+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 140ms (ActiveRecord: 30.3ms)
2018-02-02T23:14:19.338990+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a]   
2018-02-02T23:14:19.339160+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a] NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<Answer:0x00000004d173e8>):
2018-02-02T23:14:19.339198+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a]   
2018-02-02T23:14:19.339242+00:00 app[web.1]: [bb557967-7424-414b-9684-b31ad439936a] app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:77:in `destroy'
```

As you can see I get a NoMethodError (this only happens once the app has been deployed) what could be the cause of this and how can it be fixed? 
I'll post more code from my controllers and models if needed, thanks in advance :)

*edit*
full Question controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_user
    before_action :require_project
    before_action :require_user, except: [:new, :create]
    before_action :current_project, only: [:index]
    def index
        @preguntas = Question.all.order(:process)
        @project_id = request.original_url.split('.').last
        set_current_project(@project_id)
    if(@project_id.include? "http")
    @project_id = "0"
    end
        if(@project_id != "0")
            @proyecto = Project.find(@project_id)
        end 
    end

def show
    @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
    @opciones = Option.where(question_id: @pregunta)
end

def new
puts "HELLO EVERYONE NEW QUESTION"
  @pregunta = Question.new
    for option in @pregunta.options
        option.question_id = 1
        option.build
    end
end

def create
puts "HELLO EVERYONE CREATE QUESTION"
    @pregunta = Question.new(pregunta_params)
    if @pregunta.save
    @counter = 0
    @step = 1.to_f / @pregunta.options.count
    for option in @pregunta.options
        @counter = @counter + 1
        if @counter == @pregunta.options.count
            option.update_value(1.to_f)
        else
            option.update_value(@step * @counter)
        end
    end
         redirect_to @pregunta
    else
         render 'new'
    end
end
    def edit
        @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def update
puts "HELLO EVERYONE UPDATE UPDATE"
      @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
      @pregunta.options.build
      if @pregunta.update(pregunta_params)
        @counter = 0
            @step = 1.to_f / @pregunta.options.count
            for option in @pregunta.options
                @counter = @counter + 1
                if @counter == @pregunta.options.count
                    option.update_value(1.to_f)
                else
                    option.update_value(@step * @counter)
                end
            end
        redirect_to @pregunta
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end


     def destroy
        @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
        Answer.where(:question_id => @pregunta.id).destroy_all
        @pregunta.destroy
        flash[:danger] = "Se ha borrado la pregunta"
        redirect_to questions_path
    end 

    def require_same_user 
        set_project
        if current_user != @project.user && !@current_user.admin?
            flash[:danger] = "Solo puedes editar tus artículos"
            redirect_to root_path
        end 
    end 

    def require_project
        if current_user.projects.count <1 && !current_user.admin?
            redirect_to root_path
        end 
    end 

    private
        def pregunta_params
            params.require(:question).permit(:question, :value, :process, :area, :input, options_attributes: Option.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
        end
end
```

*edit*
Full Question model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord  
    has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |att| att['description'].blank? }
    validates :question, presence: true
        validates :value, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1 }
        validates :area, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }

        def count_op
            Option.where("description IS NOT NULL").where(question_id: self.id).count
        end

        def get_op
            Option.where("description IS NOT NULL").where(question_id: self.id)
        end
        def get_process_name
            case self.process
                when 1 
                    "1 - Identificación de grupo"
                when 2
                    "2 - Reflexión de desarrollo comunitario"
                when 3 
                    "3 - Problemáticas comunitarias - priorización"
                when 4 
                    "4 - Plan de trabajo comunitario"
                when 5 
                    "5 - Desarrollo de actividades y proyectos"
                when 6 
                    "6 - Operación de proyectos y seguimiento a cumplimiento de metas"
                when 7 
                    "7 - Seguimiento a proyectos comunitarios"
                when 8 
                    "8 - Fortalecimiento - operación de grupo"
                when 9 
                    "9 - Capacitación metodológica para vinculación y desarrollo comunitario"
                when 10 
                    "10 - Creación de redes y alianzas comunitarias"
                when 11 
                    "11 - Realización de planes de desarrollo local"
                when 12
                    "12 - Seguimiento a proyectos"
                when 13
                    "13 - Fortalecimiento operación de grupo"
                when 14
                    "14 - Creación de redes y alianzas institucionales"
                else
                    "Error en la fase"
            end
        end
end
```

Comment: Where are you redirecting after destroying the records? How does your controller look like?

Comment: I redirect back to questions_path, I have added the full Question Controller

Comment: Show the Question model, error most likely has roots there.

Comment: this is kinda wierd, nowhere in the code you've shown do you load an `Answer` record or call any answer relation. So I suspect that the code on heroku is not up to date with your local, or the problem is caused by some code we don't see here.

Comment: which line is line 77 in QuestionsController?

Comment: Your error is probably in one of the dependent model's controller:destroy method, which is called because of "destroy" dependency.

Comment: @BartoszPietraszko I have added the question model

Comment: @maxpleaner the code appeared after some commits in my heroku repository so I'm sure it is up to date

Comment: @Pablo I just found out my Question controller was different from the one I posted just for that line, I'll update it, the line itself is the second in the destroy method: Answer.where(:question_id => @pregunta.id).destroy_all

Comment: @goose3228 I don't have a destroy method defined in my Answer controller could that be the problem?

Comment: I suggest you removing that 73 line and everything like that. Rails active model is designed to do routine work such as destroying dependent models out of the box. If you still want to manually delete them, remove :dependent => destroy and try Answer.destroy_all(question_id: @pregunta.id). And no, you dont need destroy method in controller in order for :dependent => :destroy to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you create your models, `.answer_projects` is nil, so when it attempts to destroy `.projects`, it can't find the each of them associated with `.answer_projects`. Try changing

```
has_many :answers_projects, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :projects, through: :answers_projects, :dependent => :destroy
```

to

```
has_many :answers_projects
has_many :projects, through: :answers_projects
```

Comment: If there are no answers_projects, .answers_projects is not nil. It's an empty array.

Comment: I tried that but I sill get an error, my console reads: (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "questions" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_3d5ed4418f" on table "answers"

Comment: Can you post your questions model? At least the relationships?

Comment: when you delete a question, do you want to delete all answers associated with that question? You may need to add `has_many :answers` to your question model

Answer (score 0):

Why does you answer belongs_to :question, :dependent => :destroy?
Do you want to destroy a question when you destroy an answer?
Does you question has_many answers?

This can be the problem.

If not, I also found some improvements. You are defining a lot of instance variables (@project_id, @counter, @step and other). DO you need these variables to be accessible in views? Why don't you just use project_id, counter, step?

**EDIT**

After you posted the error in QuestionsController#destroy: Why don't you add question has_many :answers dependent destroy in your Question model? This way you don't need the destroy_all you are performing before destroying the Question.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |att| att['description'].blank? }
  validates :question, presence: true
  validates :value, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1 }
  validates :area, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
```

QuestionsController

```
def destroy
  @pregunta = Question.find(params[:id])
  @pregunta.destroy
  flash[:danger] = "Se ha borrado la pregunta"
  redirect_to questions_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I removed the dependency in the Answer model, I need them fill some values dinamically depending on the number of existing options.